# Prove an inequality x+y+z=3

Tags: inequality

If $x+y+z=3$,

x,y,z >0

prove that

$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{y+z}+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{x+z}+\frac{\sqrt{z}}{x+y}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: I solved your problem for positive variables. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your inequality in the form
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3-x}+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{3-y}+\frac{\sqrt{z}}{3-z}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$
We will prove a Lemma:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3-x}\geq \frac{1}{2}x$$
This is for all $x$ with $0<x<3$ equivalent to
$$x^2-3x+2\sqrt{x}\geq 0$$
Substituting
$t=\sqrt{x}$ this is equivalent to
$$t(2+t)(t-1)^2\geq 0$$
 Using this Lemma we can write
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3-x}+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{3-y}+\frac{\sqrt{z}}{3-z}\geq \frac{1}{2}(x+y+z)=\frac{3}{2}$$
by the Lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum of the function $$f(x,y,z)= \frac{\sqrt{x}}{y+z}+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{x+z}+\frac{\sqrt{z}}{x+y}$$ restricted to the domain $x+y+z=3$ to do this use [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).